# How Can I add date to 1 year. in X++

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

How Can I add date to 1 year. I have field with date. now i want to add another field which add 1 year to previous field (date)  in X++ code
Ex: 19/10/2010 to 18/10/2011

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
TransDate dt = 19\10\2010;
info(strfmt("date is %1",nextYr(dt)));
```

Comment: check the result, if the date is 29/02/2012 (lape year)

Answer (score 1):

You want the date before the same date next year:

```
nextYr(19\08\2011 - 1)
```

The function `nextYr` gives you the same date, so you have to subtract by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
TransDate dt = 19\10\2010;
TransDate dt_res = mkdate(dayofmth(dt), mthofyr(dt), year(dt) + 1 ) - 1;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

I got an Answer .. 
  Create a display method on the table

```
    Diplay Date m1()
{
date d;
d = this.fieldDate + 364;
return d;
}
```

just drag & drop it on the form design (grid, Group -like)
exetue it 1 year will be added to previous Date